# Getting error while doing Extractive Question Answering using the Haystack

Tags: machine-learning, nlp-question-answering, haystack

I am trying to implement the Extractive QA using the `ExtractiveQAPipeline` from Haystack. I did the following steps:

1. created the `ElasticSearchDocuemntStore`,
2. then converted files to documents using `convert_files_to_docs`,
3. written these documents to the the docstore using `"write_doc"`,
4. Then used the `BM25Retriver` and `FARMReader`.
5. The used the `ExtractiveQAPipeline` to extract the answers.

When I do pipe.run and pass in the parameters and execute it, I get the following error:

> ERROR:posthog:error uploading: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tm.hs.deepset.ai', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /batch/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

I have created the `Elasticstore` in another VM and accessing it remotely.

Can anyone please help me?

I tried recreating the document store and tested it but still getting the same error.

Comment: The problem seems related to telemetry. Read these discussions to understand better: https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/discussions/3394 https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/discussions/3235

If you want a rapid feedback, you can reach the Deepset team through Github discussions (https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/discussions) or Discord (https://haystack.deepset.ai/community)